# Installing PyQt5 on 'arm64' stopped working all of a sudden (some 'sip' issue)

Tags: python, pyqt5, sip, qmake, apple-silicon

this is a pretty macOS specific question, but I didn't know where to put it. I have an Python script that uses PyQt5. Unfortunately there is no wheel for `pyqt5` to install it with `pip` so you have to build from source, if you are on `arm64`. This is how I successfully did it till today:

1. It requires `qmake`, which I installed via `brew` (`brew install qt5`). After adding this to my path I can execute it (`which qmake` shows the correct path).
2. Then I install pyqt5 via pip with this command: `pip install pyqt5 --config-settings --confirm-license= --verbose` (pyqt5 asks for license agreement, but pip install is not interactive, hence the long command).
   As I said, till last week I could do this successfully. When I tried this today I got the error:

```
  The dbus-python package does not seem to be installed.
  These bindings will be built: Qt, pylupdate, pyrcc.
  Generating the Qt bindings...
  Generating the pylupdate bindings...
  _in_process.py: /private/var/folders/ws/vdb_nvyj35g9ck_srpvqpccm0000gn/T/pip-install-jr3725ba/pyqt5_7d0f0bcc5a7241bd8afa726e0fa5e8d1/sip/QtCore/qprocess.sip: line 99: column 5: 'Q_PID' is undefined
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

It seems thta something with `sip`-related changed. The only thing that has changed on my system was an update from Xcode14 to Xcode15. I don't really see why this should affect pyqt5 or sip, but it's the only thing I can think of.

I also tried to install `sip` via brew additionally, but this did not change anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: According to the mailing list (see the [related post](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2023-September/045508.html)), the PyQt developer released Apple Silicon wheels for PyQt5 too on their [local PyPi server](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pypi/) just a couple of days ago. They are still considered experimental, but you could test them and eventually report any issues on the same mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll test that. Interestingly, the message before that post did [exactly point to my problem](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2023-September/045507.html). Guess I'll answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the reason it did not work anymore (macOS, arm64), was due to Xcode 15. I downloaded Xcode 14.3.1 from here (https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.3.1/Xcode_14.3.1.xip), unzipped it, renamed `Xcode.app` to `Xcode_14.3.1.app` (to be able to have both versions in parallel), copied it to `/Applications` and started it. After that I set the command line tools to 14.3.1 (Settings -> Locations; there are also other ways like `xcode-select -s` and also ways with command line tools only) and just installed PyQt5 using this command: `pip install pyqt5 --config-settings --confirm-license= --verbose`. I can confirm that building PyQt5 from source works again (this still needs `qmake` from `brew` or from qt.io), so there is an incompatibility with some of the contents of Xcode 15. I'll try to find out, which one this is exactly so we might be able to transfer this to linux aarch64.